# Getting Started With Python and Django

Tags: python, django

I am newbie to the Django framework. I want to learn it and use it to develop applications. I am new to python. To learn Django, do I need knowledge of python and design patterns?

I don't know whether I should learn the design patterns, e.g. MVC, and think about writing applications or instead start to learn the language by writing complex web applications. Your suggestions are welcome.

Comment: "to learn django,do i need knowledge of python,especially fundamentals."  Is this your question?  If so, the answer is "Yes."  What more do you need to know?  Please **update** your question to make it more clear what you need to know.

Comment: @S.Lott:Edited my question.Do you think design patterns,oject-oreinted techniques are one of the fundamentals for an web application?

Comment: I still don't understand your question.  "design patterns,MVC and think about writing applications or ... writing applications from the first day."  You must write applications from the first day to learn the fundamentals.  Do you mean "writing complex web applications from the first day?"

Comment: @S.Lott:Yes i meant complex web applications.

Comment: @blakcaps: Updating the question is sufficient.  You don't need to add lots of status report comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jump right in to Django. You can do it, and learn as you go. [Djangobook](http://djangobook.com/) will teach you the foundations of Django to start building apps.

One of thing to keep in mind as far as Python itself goes is using [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) to style your code, it'll make it easier down  the road when others are looking at your code, whether for help or when working on projects.

@S.Lott is right, foundations are important

However, I think it's possible to learn the foundation while building an actual project/app and having some fun/gaining some experience at the same time.
(note: such as the provided tutorials from django, like the [poll app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/))

**Edit:** I'd like to point out that in the comments below, I no longer support my answer for this particular situation. If the person is experienced with programming and language fundamentals, to me they have the knowledge necessary and the language is merely the tool they use. If that is the case I don't see anything wrong with picking up some of the specifics of a language while using a framework.

Comment: "there's no reason you can't learn the foundation while building an actual project/app".  That's generally untrue.  I didn't think muy comment suggested that. The foundations aren't trivial, and muddying up Python and Django into a single course of learning is a terrible idea.

Comment: Point taken. Would you say that's true in tutorial projects like the django poll or blog apps as well though? I hope my edit separates your point from my continued thought.

Comment: @TomHarrigan: Yes.  I can't see how anyone could learn  a complex web application framework without solid language fundamentals.  I've had enough trouble teaching a language to "professional" programmers who don't seem to get the fundamentals of programming in the first place.  Programming is **hard** and we need to respect how deeply hard it is.  One thing at a time.

Comment: Looking at the clarifications to the original question, I agree with you. I assumed non-language specific fundamentals, which could have been me misreading the question to begin with.

Comment: the comment on "muddying up Python and Django" makes a lot of sense too after some thought. Thanks.

Comment: I agree on the fundamentals, but here's something to think about: Most python programming involves pulling in libraries to help do things, even at the earliest stages. I don't see why having that library be Django should be a problem. It's well documented and widely used. Of course you'll want to throw away your first few apps (or rewrite) eventually, but that's how learning works :/

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest learning the basics of Python and at least the MVC design pattern first.

From there, yes, go ahead and starting creating a project in Django, it's the best way to learn Django.

As far as "python fundamentals" that means the obvious basic syntax and keywords. From there, it's more important that you understand "programming in general" especially the Object-oriented programming paradigm.

Comment: Learning the MVC design pattern before using django will just frustrate you, because the django people don't understand at all how it works.

Comment: hehe, perhaps. But understanding that MVC is indeed itself a Design Pattern, is important to understand, so you can then see how Django implements it.

Comment: More information on Django's odd interpretation of MVC (more sensibly called MTV): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/general/#django-appears-to-be-a-mvc-framework-but-you-call-the-controller-the-view-and-the-view-the-template-how-come-you-don-t-use-the-standard-names

Answer (score 2):

> What do you term as python fundamentals

How's about the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/)?

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest [MDN Django](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django) tutorial. In this tutorial you will develop a simple local library app and deploy it on heroku. You will get a good idea on how to develop a web app and deploy it on a cloud platform.